# Script to convert files inside directories to dos2unix format

Tags: bash, solaris

I am trying to implement a bash script that should convert all the dos files inside different directories to unix format in Solaris.

Can some one please provide me any script..

below is one example as what I am looking for.

```
var1/tmp/pkg/app/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/domains/deveng_wl1/DomainSetenv.sh
var1/tmp/app/weblogic/setenv.sh
var1/tmp/app/weblogic/prestige/scripts/abc
var1/tmp/pkg/app/weblogic/prestige/scripts/xyz
```

all these files need to be converted to dos2unix format. Appreciate if some one can share one script

Thanks

Comment: Be VERY careful you do not convert files you don't want to. What is the base directory (ies) you want to convert ALL files in? You list 3, e.g. `var1/tmp/pkg/app/weblogic/Oracle, var1/tmp/app/weblogic, var1/tmp/pkg/app/weblogic/prestige`? Are there any files below those directories you do NOT want to convert?

Comment: @David : Thanks for the response, above is just an example i share to give an idea.. I want to find those similar files in each directory and convert to dos2unix format in solaris..

Comment: Yes, I know, but the solution will depend on ALL files below some base directories being converted, e.g. `find dir1 dir2 dir3 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix` will convert ALL files below `dir1 dir2 & dir3`. That's why I asked. Otherwise you will have to process each file to determine the line-endings present to build a list to convert.

Comment: I tried something like above, but it is only searching the file not able to convert to dos2 unix format. below is the one i did..


function dos_conversion() {
      d_conv=${ROOT_DIR}/app/weblogic
      find $d_conv -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec dos2unix $d_conv/*.sh $d_conv/*.sh 2</dev/null
      echo " Dos Files converted to Unix Format"

Comment: That is confusing. `find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix` will convert every file below `dir1`. Do you have sufficient permissions to modify the files below each of the directories? (either user-owned, member of the owning group or world-writable -- with write permission (e.g. `7` in the octet))

Comment: You would need `-exec dos2unix '{}' \;` if you want to use `-exec` (`dos2unix $d_conv/.sh $d_conv/*.sh` will not do it) Also, why put it in a function? Simply `d_conv=${ROOT_DIR}/app/weblogic; find "$d_conv" -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec dos2unix '{}' \;`

Comment: I did try that option, but it did not work , I am not sure, how to use exactly. Is it possible for you to correct that line..

Comment: Note the change `-iname "*.sh"`

Comment: find $d_conv -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix $d_conv/* $d_conv/* 2</dev/null

Comment: the above logic is not converting all the files.. only it pick the last file from all the searched directory and convert. I want all the files to be converted, 
for eg : DomainSetenv.sh, setenv.sh, abc, xyz and which ever it exist as files..

Comment: `find "$d_conv" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix` is all that is needed (and you put backticks around code in comments to format as code). Why are you adding `$d_conv/* $d_conv/* 2</dev/null`?  (add your `-iname "*.sh"` to only select files ending in `"sh"`)

Comment: + xargs -0 dos2unix
usage: dos2unix [ -ascii ] [ -iso ] [ -7 ] [ originalfile [ convertedfile ] ]

Comment: I got the above error by running your script idea.. I am trying in solaris.
Just want to double check would below is the command in solaris to convert dos2unix
dos2unix filename filename 2<dev/null

Comment: I'm not familiar with anything that would be different with either `find` or `xargs` on Solaris, `dos2unix` is the same. Are the files windows file in UTF-16 or UTF-32 format that may be giving Solaris problems. I don't know if the Solaris `dos2unix` will handle the conversion to UTF-8. Pick any file you are trying to convert and show the output of `file somefilename`. Also pick one file and run `dos2unix somefilename` and see if there are any problems with a single conversion.

Comment: i did create empty files and tried to convert as well, as part of testing.. the below command is like a hacking command where it work without any error

dos2unix filename filename 2<dev/null

Comment: It's not working without error, you are redirecting the errors to `/dev/null` (in a backwards way). What does `dos2unix filename` show on any file that is a DOS file?

Comment: is there any option to chat real time, I can show where exactly I am getting the error

Comment: The `"Continue in chat"` box should have shown up long ago -- I don't know why it isn't shown. Concentrate on a single file conversion, e.g. `dos2unix filename`. It should run without error (outputting the filename it is converting). If there are any problems with a single conversion, then obviously, multiple conversions will fail.

Comment: devsl1$ dos2unix DomainSetenv.sh
could not open /dev/kbd to get keyboard type US keyboard assumed
could not get keyboard type US keyboard assumed
wkejwkejw
deveng_wl1$ dos2unix DomainSetenv.sh DomainSetenv.sh 2</dev/null
devsl1$

Comment: above is the error, if you have "continue in chat" option, then can you please give me an invite..

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa... You do not just run `dos2unix` in a willy-nilly fashion so it is picking up files in `/dev` or `/proc` or `/sys` filesystems. You want to target only the files that `file filename` shows has CR/LF line-endings. That should only be files that have been transferred from windows to your Solaris box in some manner. How many files do you need to convert? I suspect No-chat has something to do with Cyrus posting the first comment, and then deleting that comment that has messed it up. Usually after the 3rd comment, the option to chat pops up.

Comment: My requirement is to check and convert all the files inside directories from dos to unix format.. so i choose the above command, it will automatically convert either it is dos or unix,

Comment: But, the script i made is not converting all, only converting one file and stop the execution.